# Koudoku - subscriptions for listings that are owned by users, rails 4, no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, nomethoderror

Rails n00b here.  I'm attempting to integrate the Koudoku gem (seems to be a great way to add subscription billing with stripe) into a rails 4 app; I have listings, that are owned by users, however each listing has it's own subscription.  Therefore a user has many listings, but a listing has only one subscription

Following the readme instructions at https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku , I ran rails g koudoku:install listing (attaching to listings vs users)

I loaded 3 pricing plans into my stripe account and loaded the API keys into the rails app

When I attempt to go to the pricing page (main_app.pricing_path ), it's throwing the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Koudoku::SubscriptionsController#index 
undefined method `subscription' for #<User:0x007fc61f79ecc0>
```

The index action in the subscriptions controller is:

```
def index

  # don't bother showing the index if they've already got a subscription.
  if current_owner and current_owner.subscription.present?
    redirect_to koudoku.edit_owner_subscription_path(current_owner, current_owner.subscription)
  end

  # Load all plans.
  @plans = ::Plan.order(:display_order).all

  # Don't prep a subscription unless a user is authenticated.
  unless no_owner?
    # we should also set the owner of the subscription here.
    @subscription = ::Subscription.new({Koudoku.owner_id_sym => @owner.id})
    # e.g. @subscription.user = @owner
    @subscription.send Koudoku.owner_assignment_sym, @owner
  end

end
```

Ideas of where I'm going wrong?  Anyone run across a beginners guide to using this gem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue with the way rails 4 installs the routes. Looks like there is a pull request pending. https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/issues/53

Comment: FIXED: https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/issues/53 ==> https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/pull/54

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is installing on listing and not user. I have not had any luck with doing that.

Try it on users and see if that helps.